# add class to object stored in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Array- myArray which is filled with objects obtained while looping using ".each"

Now I want to add a class .active

the array object can be printed using alert and shows correct innerhtml.

but how do i add class to the object?

Code:-

```
var myArray=new Array();
```

I tried this:-

```
$(myArray[1]).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Please share the `.each` loop as well

Answer (score 3):

Try mapping through your array:

```
$.map(myArray, function(elem) {
    $(elem).addClass('active');
});
```

**Edit:** A not so misleading way (thx @Sébastien RoccaSerra):

```
$.each(myArray, function(i,elem) {
    $(elem).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Your exemple works, but can be misleading. The 'map' function is more often used to produce a new array than to exert side effects on items. The 'each' function is more appropriate to iterate a function across an array. Just replacing 'map' with 'each' in your example looks more intention revealing to me. Cheers!

Comment: @Sébastien RoccaSerra I agree.

Comment: @inti  of course it does. Use ES5 shim to support legacy browsers. `Array.prototype.map` is part of the standard.

Comment: @SebastienRoccaSerra apart from that `$.each` supplies the key as the first parameter and the value as the second

Comment: @Raynos `$(myArray.map(function(v) { return v; }))` equals `$(myArray)` so why use map here, or am I missing something?

Comment: @inti I was trying to convert jQuery objects to DOM objects but I failed. It's a useless statement.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
myArray[1].addClass('active');
```

or

```
myArray.eq(1).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(myArray)[1].addClass('active');
```

Comment: `$(myArray)[1]` is a DOM element and has no function `addClass` or am I wrong?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if 'myArray' contains DOM elements, '$(myArray)' would be a collection of jQuery objects, which you can iterate with '.each()' and referencing to with '$(myArray)[x]', from what I know.

Comment: You are right. Not my day today. `$(myArray)[1][0]` would be the DOM element of the 2nd entry in `$(myArray)`.